# error A2070: invalid instruction operands while using nested while loop in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I am trying nested while loop in assembly using masm. I am getting the "error A2070: invalid instruction operands" at line 15 i.e at the endw directive of internal while loop while running the following code.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
i byte 1
j byte 2
.code
main PROC  
xor eax,eax
 .while i<5
mov j, 2
.while j<i
    mov al, j
    call writeDec
    call crlf
    inc j
.endw
inc i
 .endw
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

I cant find the reason for this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Related: [another Q&A about using `mov [esi], [edi]` explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632907/i-get-anerror-a2070-invalid-instruction-operands-how-can-i-resolved-this), instead of through MASM's "high level" macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
.while j<i
```

You cannot compare two memory contents directly. It is possible to compare a memory content with a register, e.g.:

```
mov dl, i
.while j<dl
```

BTW: Don't trust an "alien" function (Irvine's `WriteDec` and `Crlf`). When a register unintentionally changes its contents, this can due to such a function.